# How to compare the new password with the old at server side in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In my meteor project, before reset the password, I need to check whether the new password is same with the old. How can i do? just encrypt the new password or other better idea?

Comment: Yes, just try to validate the new password before changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Accounts._checkPassword` [David Weldon's blog](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/check-password)